# тег checkbox в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите как в строке использовать checkbox, таким образом чтоб выделять несколько статей и удалять. У меня получается в этом случае по-одной удаление.

```
do
{
 printf("<p><input name='id' type='checkbox'  value='%s'><label>%s</label></p>",$myrow["id"],$myrow["name"]);

}

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

форма для вывода:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<?
$i=0;
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <input name="id[<?=$i++?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$myrow['id']?>"><label><?=$myrow['name']?></label>
    <?//в этом случае к имени чекбокса добавляем [] с идентификатором внутри [$i], что позволяет нам получить результат в виде массива из выбранных элементов. (идентификатор должен быть уникальным)

}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Удалить"/>
</form>
```

обработка запроса:

```
<?
print_r($_REQUEST['id']); //смотрим что получили
if($_REQUEST['id']){
$ids = implode(',',$_REQUEST['id']);
mysql_query("delete from table where id in (".$ids.")"); //удаляем
?>Удалено <?=count($_REQUEST['id'])?> записей, имеющие id: <?=$ids;
}else{
?>Ничего не удалено.<?}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает) а теперь как убрать оповещение при невыделенных флажках? Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in
 и добавить сообщения что удалены записи?

Comment: Смотрите исправления, это самый простой вариант, который будет выдавать верное количество и id при условии, что с момента вывода формы до её обработки с базой не проводились операций типа delete и update, затронувших выбранные id'шники )

Comment: }
else echo 'Ничего не удалено.';

?>
изменил немного, а то сливает вместе "удалено записей......ничего не удалено."
работает)спасибо еще раз)

Comment: угу точно )

Comment: else{
?>Ничего не удалено.<?} хм..так у меня синтаксическую показывает(

else{ 
?>Ничего не удалено.<?;}?> так нет